# Angular Firebase enable persiste login for multiple apps

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a project where it's using Firebase.To login on the project users uses email/password login and what I want to do is to have the option to persiste the login. So for so good, I was able to do that.

> Angular version 13
>
> AngularFire version 7

The problem is that depending on some configs the user may need to use a different app than the one that is initialized on the Module, so I initialize it on the `AuthService`.

When I use the app initialized on the module, the persistence works out of the box without any other code, unles I want to remove persistence.

But when I use an app initialized on the service, the login doesn't persist, and I have no clue why it's happening. This is how I'm doing:

**app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, routerConfig),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.defaultApp, 'defaultApp'),

        //...
    ],
    // ...
})
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import 'firebase/firestore';
import auth = firebase.auth;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private appStoreAdm;

    constructor() {
        this.appStoreAdm = firebase.initializeApp(environment.appStoreAdm, 'appStoreAdm');
        this.appStoreAdm.firestore().enablePersistence();

        // Other apps initialized here same as above
    }

    public async login(app:string, email: string, password: string, remember: boolean): Promise<auth.UserCredential> {
        console.log({ email, password, remember });

        const persist = remember
            ? firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL
            : firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION;

        await this[app].auth().setPersistence(persist);
        return this[app].auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }
}
```

The login process works always as expected. I can create users on the correct app and then login correctly as well. However, using the option `Remember Me` ONLY works if using the default app initialized on the App Module.

Is there a way to make it work? How?